# Under bathroom sink piping (exposed)

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink, pipe, drainage

We are looking at setting up the piping for under our wall mounted sink (no vanity, ie, piping will be exposed). And after our contractor finished putting the wall we noticed that the hole from the wall is not going to be aligned with the hole from the sink (faucet is wall mounted and cannot be moved, so we need to deal with the way it is).

We would like to use the below p-trap (purchased already, but can be returned if it is not going to work).
[image]

We have sketched below our layout with some dimensions.  If anyone has any suggestions as to what sort of pipes (ideally chrome finish to match the p-trap) we can use to get, somehow, an acceptable result.

[image]

Suggestions are welcome
Thanks

PS: We cannot break the wall and re-route the drain pipe as there are pipes on the way, so whatever we do has to be outside the wall (ie.: visible), we will likely put a shelf for towels below that could help cover a bit the piping.

Answer 1 layout:
Thank you bcworkz for your answer, can you let me know if the below is what you are suggesting? Also, what sort of adapters would you use for the joints (at the wall top end and around the hole in the wall).  Thanks again

[image]

**Final Product**
Hi guys, first wanted to thank you bcworkz for your answer. Find below the final product. We might end up putting up a small shelf that will fill with spare towels to cover that extra piping the back.

[image]

Comment: What is the question? Do you need help installing the pipes, designing the layout, or something else?

Comment: I'm asking for suggestions on pipe sections that i could use, in conjunction with that p-trap and my layout.

Comment: ... and I guess designing the layout.

Comment: That first picture you included is not a P trap..

Comment: What are the dimensions of the trap?

Comment: Apologies, not sure how you call that sort of trap, on their website they call it P-Trap and Pop-Up drain (http://www.kraususa.com/parts/bathroom-sinks/pt-50-pu-10ch-p-trap-and-pop-up-drain-chrome-1.html#box-Specifications)

The dimensions are: lenght 15in, depth 7in.  I am not home at the moment, but i am guessing 15 in is the measure from hole of the sink to bottom of the trap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a drum trap, not a P-Trap. Be sure it's listed to comply with your code requirements. Looks slick anyway. You'll need a 45 degree chrome compression ell and maybe some extra pipe. You'll end up with the trap arm out of the drum running at a 45 degree horizontal angle to the wall. It will be cut quite short before it enters the ell. Upon exiting the ell, it should be a straight shot to the wall connection. The remaining trap arm you cut off may or may not be long enough for this. It then ties into the wall pipe with the same adapter fitting you would normally have used.

The trap arm runs entirely horizontal, despite the ell, with just enough slope to drain (1/4" per foot). The only significant vertical drop is in the tail piece that drops straight down from the sink. If you prefer the 45 degree segment to be closer to the wall, you could do a variation using two 45 degree ells, such that the trap arm out of the drum goes straight back for a distance before making a dog leg to the wall drain.

Comment: I have modified my question to include what I understand your layout is.  what adapters do you recommend I use for the other joints (top wall and around the hole on the wall)

Comment: Also, i have just noticed that i can rotate the trap so that the horizontal pipe that comes out of it can be at an angle. Knowing this, what pipe join connectors to you suggest we use for: 1. join the pipe that is in the hole in the wall and 2. the join of the horizontal pipe and the pipe that comes straight up from the hole. Thx